# How to part with Colleagues

Tags: colleagues, resignation, offices

I have put in my two weeks' resignation notice effective next week Friday however, I have not told any of my colleagues I am leaving. we are seven in the office, only told my supervisor and CEO. I have been here for four months and I coordinate the social events so made friends with all of them. We have pizza lunch today which I organized and I feel I should let them know I am leaving but don't know if that is even allowed. Is it ok to just leave next week on Friday. I am sure they would all ask of me if they don't see me on Monday. Is there a better way to do this?

Update:
Thanks for your advice. I told them at the Pizza lunch and it was an emotional moment with a lot of...i will miss you...haha

Comment: Is there a reason you would choose to avoid saying goodbye?

Comment: No, absolutely no reason. I just know it will be awkward if I just disappear

Answer (score 8):

**Ask your supervisor**, though usually you are allowed to say so after officially resigning.

Leaving without notice would not be too polite of you. People come and go and four months is not much, but they deserve to know.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it ok to just leave next week on Friday.

Whatever else you do to part ways, **please don't do this**. This will create a serious communication gap between you and them irrespective of whether you wish to remain in touch in future on not. This is never a good thing from both professional and interpersonal standpoint.

Based on how soon/late it's allowed in your workplace, you should inform your colleagues about your move. Inform them all together in a group email, group message. Put it nicely stating that how it has been a nice experience working and bonding with them. You can gently give a reasoning explaining your move.

Comment: Exactly. Don't say anything negative (don't burn bridges). You can always keep the reason generic (looking for new opportunities). If you want to keep in touch with any of them, add home contact information.

Answer (score 0):

> We have pizza lunch today which I organized and I feel I should let
>   them know I am leaving but don't know if that is even allowed.

Ask your boss if that would be allowed.

> Is it ok to just leave next week on Friday.

Yes, of course that would be okay. But it wouldn't be very nice.

> I am sure they would all ask of me if they don't see me on Monday. Is
>   there a better way to do this?

The best way is to discuss this with your boss when you give your resignation.

Since that didn't happen, the next best was is to discuss this with your boss now. Something like "I'd like to let folks know that I'll be leaving. Would that be okay, or would you rather let them know yourself?" would be appropriate.

Most likely you will be free to tell your colleagues whenever you choose. But it's possible that management would prefer to break the news themselves.